# Чтение данных из файла в директории proc

Tags: c++, linux

Пишу программу на си++ и возникла необходимость читать файл /proc/meminfo. Но на сервере запускается несколько копий данной программы, в связи с чем стала необходимость читать данный файл без перебоев между процессами.

Есть ли какой-нибудь метод или функция уже готовая в си++, который бы обеспечило такую возможность и всегда можно было бы получить данные для каждого процесса без ошибки скажем чтения? Или придется использовать fopen с каким нибудь lock?

Comment: Там же информации на килобайт всего. сделайте буфер килобайта 4 и читайте за один вызов обычной функции read. И какие собственно перебои могут быть из за чтения разными процессами

Comment: о каких перебоях идёт речь? Можете пример  привести? (код + последовательность команд)

Comment: Имелось ввиду момент времени когда первый процесс (первая копия программы) читает, и в этот же момент начинает читать второй процесс. Не получит ли отлуп второй процесс (с помощью fopen) из-за lock во время чтения первого процесса?

Comment: @nerik, Отлупа не будет, а вот данные там нестабильные. Оба процесса получат скорее всего (в нагруженной как-то системе) разные данные, хотя и консистентные.